# Animaciones en mapa en wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, plugin

Estoy desarrollando un sitio con wordpress en el cual necesito crear ciertas animaciones a un mapa.

Existe algún **plugin** de wordpress o **script** con **jquery** que solucione esta petición por parte del cliente.

1.- Los países de color verde agregar un **marcador** 
2.- Al pasar el **mouse** por alguno de estos lugares el marcador ejecute una **animación** como resaltar o crecer.

Me servirá de mucho su ayuda ya que tengo varios días buscando una solución a este problema. La idea de esto es crear un mapa dinámico y atractivo para el usuario final

[image: Mapa]

Comment: qué tienes hecho hasta ahora? el mapa ya lo tienes andando? Tiene colores o comportamiento para mouseover?

Comment: Por el momento es solo una imagen que me dieron de ejemplo. trate de hacerlo con css pero es un poco mas complicado al momento de hacerse responsivo. Este es el sitio para en la seccion de contacto [http://www.fourdreams.com.mx/proyectos/citro/contacto/]

Comment: :v ay flash player que pena que hayas muerto.

Comment: jaja debe de existir alguna forma. alguien experto en wordpress ?? css ?? algun plugin para wordpress ?? :'v

Comment: No sé si haya un plugin, pero eso que muestras se puede hacer con D3. http://bl.ocks.org/ericcoopey/ff45f603352fb7475c85

Comment: También encontré [AMCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/download/) que tiene un plugin para wordpress, pero no sé cuan fácil sea customizarlo. [Mira este ejemplo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/zooming-to-countries-map/)